# Home text is not linking to the "home page" in login page

Tags: checkout, login

please visit this link :

http://schoolboards4.newtrendzonline.com/index.php/customer/account/login/

on the left side you can see Home/Login , but if click on "home", it's not linking to the home page.

this is breadcrumbs.phtml file => http://pastebin.com/3kzMRFT2

after registration, it will display " Home/ My Account".

If we click "home" on that page also, its not linking to the home page.

let me know if you need any other files.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: did u added this bread crumbs urself ?

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply, before only it was in theme.

Comment: please check in the theme can you find the breadcrumb code

Comment: okay, i will try.....

Comment: is i have to search other file than in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how those breadcrumbs links are built but I recommend you this extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-account-breadcrumbs.html.
It lets you add breadcrumbs for the customer account pages. You can even configure what pages to have breadcrumbs and which shouldn't.
Even it it says it works for versions up to 1.6 it should work for later version.

Comment: Magento devolopers got lot of problems, so they prayed to god, so god created Marius to help magento devolopers.... Thanks a lot.... it worked for 1.8 version.

Answer (score 2):

try to add this in your themes local.xml file

```
<customer_account_login translate="label">
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>Home</label>
                    <title>Home</title>
                    <link>/</link>
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Login</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>Login</label>
                    <title>Login</title>
                    <link>/customer/account/login/</link>
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_login>
```

Comment: hi, thanks alot for reply. there is no local.xml file in theme layout, also in base > default theme.

Comment: yes you should have to create the local.xml file in your theme's dir

Comment: yes, i added to the theme layout, but check now, home text is not linking.

Comment: try to findout from where the breadcrumbs coming from and add their <link>/</link>

Comment: okay, i will try....

Comment: i got in lib/zend/view/helper/navigatiob/breadcrumbs.php = >http://pastebin.com/h4uHNQfH

Comment: you can see breadcrumbs here : this layout/customer.xml -> http://pastebin.com/WNxZm3w8

Comment: you can see breadcrumbs here layout/checkout.xml - > http://pastebin.com/cXQPe9JW

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for your support. i used this extension provided by marius : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-account-breadcrumbs.html it solved the problem.